# How to open an external executable file using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How to open an external executable file using jenkins

I tried it in execute window batch command like

```
cd c:\EMailer\
call testcompete.exe
```

But it is not working
then i tried

```
start testcomplete.exe
```

This testcomplete will run the automated site and write a text file .
It is also not working.Is there any pluggin or method in jenkin to open external executable files?
[image] showing prompt when testcomplete trying to start

Comment: "open an external executable" is not clear... Do you just want to run it? if so, both options you noted should work. Do you want to fork it and not wait for it? You should remember that the process runs under the java, which is running Jenkins.

Comment: @EldadAK Means it is not opening any testcompete window

Comment: 1. If you run it from command line, does it run? 2. Is Jenkins running as a service?

Comment: 1. yes it is running through command prompt  2.Yes  Jenkins is running as service

Comment: Also the testcomplete is running as service

Comment: Try setting the Jenkins service to "Allow service to interact with the desktop". Does it help (after service restart)?

Comment: Thanks for your support. Now we are getting the application but there is a prompt message coming in between asking whether I need to allow it or not?

Comment: This is a windows 7 issue (I assume). You should set the service to run as administrator by default (I'm not sure exactly how it's done, but I know it can), but looks like you are on the right path...

Comment: we tried is with run as administrator ,but it is showing the same prompt.I added the prompt message with the question

Comment: We changed the operating system to windows xp sp3 ,then the testcomplete and its corresponding browser is opening correctly, but it can't fill the data

Comment: This is more related to the testcomplete implementation or environment, which I don't know at all. Sorry...

Comment: @EldadAK Ok Please make your 3rd comment as answer.Thanks

Comment: @EldadAK I followed the same steps of "Allow service to interact with the desktop". But still nothing. Any idea? Also, 1. yes it is running through command prompt 2.Yes Jenkins is running as service.
Extension is not helping as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the Jenkins service to "Allow service to interact with the desktop". This will allow Jenkins to use the desktop as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **Windows Exe Runner** Plugin in Jenkins.

For more information: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Windows+Exe+Runner+Plugin